# Exam recall of $\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3=(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^3-3(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)+3\alpha\beta\gamma$

Tags: cubics

From my book:

> You can find a similar result for the sum of the cubes of a cubic
> equation by multiplying out $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^3.$
>
> - The rules for sums of cubes:
>   -
>
>   - **Quadratic:** $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 = (\alpha + \beta)^3-3\alpha\beta(\alpha + \beta)$
>   - **Cubic:** $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 = (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^3 - 3(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)( \alpha\beta +
>     \beta\gamma + \gamma\alpha) + 3\alpha\beta\gamma $

The quadratic one is easy to see, but I don't know how to see where the cubic one comes from in a simple way/ with as little working as possible? I tried a few ways of expanding $( \alpha + \beta + \gamma )^{3}$, but didn't get the result easily (or at all).

Comment: apply the "quadratic" rule twice and note $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3a^2b-3ab^2$

Comment: I tried that but didn't get the result. Not quickly anyway. I feel like there ought to be a more intuitive way of seeing the result. Either that or you're just meant to accept and memorise it. Ok now it looks like you're referring to the quadratic rule. This question is about the cubic one below it.

Comment: There is a general *theorem* that each symmetric polynomial in $n$ variables is a polynomials in what are called the "elementary symmetric functions" of those variables (their sum, the sum of their products two at a time, ..., the sum of their products $n$ at a time, with that last expression being the usual product).  What you're seeing is how to write $x^3 + y^3 + z^3$ in terms of the elementary symmetric functions of three variables (namely $x+y+z$, $xy+xz+yz$, and $xyz$). Don't expect there to be some quick way to derive this.  Read a proof of the theorem; some are algorithmic.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities for a nice generalisation. The point of @J.W.Tanner is that you can derive the "cubic rule" by applying the "quadratic " rule twice, first to $\alpha$ and $\beta+\gamma$, then to $\beta$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: They are both cubic (raised to the third power). One is binomial (two terms), and the other is trinomial (three terms).

Comment: @Arthur:  I agree; that's why I put "quadratic" in quotes

Comment: By the way, OP, try to steer clear of people that call obviously cubic expressions quadratic. Perhaps they wanted to say *binomial,* but if one wants to teach something, one must be sure one really knows what one is saying. Just saying that the binomial $\alpha^3+\beta^3$ *isn't* quadratic; it's **cubic!**

Comment: " I feel like there ought to be a more intuitive way of seeing the result. Either that or you're just meant to accept and memorise it." Both work for me.  this is listing all combinations of three terms.  There's each term cubed, plus each term times another term squared (three times each) and all the terms multiplied together (six times).  And $(a+b+c)($ every combination of two terms$)$ will be three occurances of a term times a square of another term and three times the product of every term.  So $(a+b+c)^3=$ sum of all cubes + $3(a+b+c)($ every combination of two terms$)+3abc$.

Comment: fleablood- Yes I was almost there when I posted this question, but I stopped because I thought it would be "weird" for the -3 to come from 6 - 9, and I thought there would be a more straightforward way of obtaining the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an exam, probably memorising this cubic rule is best. But let's say you're in an exam and failed to memorise the cubic rule. Then you just need to do 2 things and then deriving the rule is easy.

1. Remember you can expand the brackets of $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^{3}$ as such:

$\quad(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^{3} = \alpha^{3} + \beta^{3} + \gamma^{3} + 3( \alpha\beta^{2}+\alpha\gamma^{2}+\beta\alpha^{2}+\beta\gamma^{2}+\gamma\alpha^{2}+\gamma\beta^{2}) + 6\alpha\beta\gamma$,

which has 3 + 18 + 6 = 27 terms, so we haven't missed out any terms. And you can remember to use:

2. $\quad(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma) = 3\alpha\beta\gamma + (\alpha\beta^{2}+\alpha\gamma^{2}+\beta\alpha^{2}+\beta\gamma^{2}+\gamma\alpha^{2}+\gamma\beta^{2})$

Now eliminate $\alpha\beta^{2}+\alpha\gamma^{2}+\beta\alpha^{2}+\beta\gamma^{2}+\gamma\alpha^{2}+\gamma\beta^{2}$ from both equations.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=\beta+\gamma$. So, I have: $$(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^3=(\alpha+k)^3=\alpha^3+k^3+3\alpha k^2+3\alpha^2k=\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+3\gamma^2\beta+3\beta^2\gamma+3\alpha^2\gamma+3\alpha^2\beta+3\alpha\beta^2+3\alpha\gamma^2+6\alpha\beta\gamma=\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+3\gamma(\gamma\beta+\alpha\beta+\gamma\alpha)+3\alpha(\alpha\gamma+\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta)+3\beta(\alpha\gamma+\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta)-3\alpha\beta\gamma=\alpha^3+\beta^3+\gamma^3+3(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)(\alpha\gamma+\alpha\beta+\gamma\beta)-3\alpha\beta\gamma$$

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

$(a + b +c)^3 = (a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c) =$

$a^3 + a^2b + a^2c + aba + ab^2 + abc + aca+acb + ac^2 + ba^2 + bab + bac +b^2a + b^3 +b^2c + bca + bcb + bc^2 + ca^2 + cab + cac + cba + cb^2 + cbc + c^2 a + c^2b+ c^3=$

$(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3(a^2 b + a^2c +  ab^2 +b^2c + ac^2+bc^2) +6abc=$

$(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3([a^2b + a^2c + abc]+ [ab^2 + abc + b^2c] + [abc + ac^2 + bc^2] + 3abc =$

$(a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3(a(ab + ac +bc) + b(ab + ac +bc) + c(ab +ac +bc)) + 3abc =$

$(a^3 + b^3 +c^3) +3(a+b+c)(ab+ac + bc) + 3abc$

......

$(a+b+c)^3 = $ sum of all the cubes of all terms ($a^3 + b^3 +c^3)+$

$3$ ways of getting one of the terms times the square of the sum of the other two terms $

$3[ a(b+c)^2 + b(a+c)^2 + c(a+b)^2]$.

Meanwhile looking at each $a(b+c)(b+c)$ and $b(a+c)(a+c)$ and $c(a+b)(a+b)$ we have every term times the some of product of any two terms:  That is to say, from $a(b+c)(b+c)$ we can extract $a(b^2)$ and $a(bc)$(twice) and $a(c^2)$ whereas for $b(a+c)(a+c)$ we can extract $a(ab)$ and $a(bc)$ twice and so on.  We have three of each $a(b+c)^2$ so we can do this extraction for each $a,b,c$ so from $3[ a(b+c)^2 + b(a+c)^2 + c(a+b)^2]$ we can get $a(ab+bc+ac)$ and $b(ab+bc + ac)$ and $c(ab+bc+ac)$, as well as three extra $abc$s.

So this should intuitively give us the result.

==== third "what this finger painting is supposed to represent" explanation =====

$(a + b+ c)^3=(a+b+c)(a+b+c)(a+b+c)$ should be a sum of the $27$ different combinations of three terms.  They are:

- terms of the form $x^3$.  There are three of those; one for $x=a,b,c$
- terms of the form $x^2y$.  for each $a,b,$ or $c$ there are two out of three of the triplets, $(a+b+c)$ where the two $x$s can come from, and the $y$ must  come from the third triplet.  That is to say. to get $\color{blue}{x^2y}$, we get it from $(\color{blue}x + \color{gray}y + \color{gray}z)(\color{blue}x + \color{gray}y + \color{gray}z)(\color{gray}x + \color{blue}y + \color{gray}z)$ and there are ${3\choose 2}={3\choose 1} = 3$ ways to choose which of $x$s  and which $y$ to use. And of $a,b,c$ there are $3$ choices for the $x$ and $2$ remaining for the $y$. And of those $6$ there are $3$ choices of how you pick the $x$ and $y$ so those are $18$ of these $x^2y$s.
- the remaining six terms are the terms $abc$.  It makes sense that there are $6! =6$ of these terms, because there are $3$ triplets to choose the $a$ from; once choosen there are $2$ remaining triplets to choose the $b$, etc.

The second item on the list can be written as $3(a^2(b+c) + b^2(a+c)+c^2(b+c)$ or purhaps more  "balanced" as $3(a(ab+ac) + b(ab + bc) + c(ab + bc))$.

And we can "borrow " three of the $abc$s from the third item on the list so that $3(a(ab + ac + bc) + b(ab + ac + bc)+ c(ab + ac + bc) ) = 3(a+b+c)(ab + bc + ac)$

So ultimately

$(a+b+c)^3 = (a^3 + b^3 + c^3) + 3(a+b+c)(ab+bc + ac) + 3abc$.

That's nothing more or less than the sum of all combinations presented and factored in a fairly convenient and simple form.

Comment: Yes. Note that in the 3rd line, there are 3 + 3*6 + 6 = 27 terms, which means we haven't missed out/ forgotten any terms because we expected 3*3*3 = 27 terms.

Comment: I can go from 1st line to 3rd line OK. But then the rest is kind of long and less easy to see than what you wrote in your comment to the OP.

Comment: Yeah, there's a reason mathematician tend to go straight into math instead of leaning back and saying "and do you get it, this part just cycles from that part and if you pull those apart that's all we're really doing".  But the OP did say he didn't have an intuition and it was hard to memorize.  I wanted to express some idea of the symmetry and exhaustively.

Comment: I should have been clearer in the OP. The problem is not “I don’t see at all where the result come from”. The problem is, “how can you get to the result really quickly under exam conditions, if you forget the formula?” Your explanation seems overly long and I prefer my answer

Answer (score -1):

There is a *multinomial formula*. For three variables, it reads as
$$(x+y+z)^n=\sum_{i+j+k=n}\frac{n!}{i!\,j!\,k!}\,x^i y^j z^k$$
and in particular
\begin{multline}(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3\\+3x^2y+3xy^2+3y^2z+3yz^2+3z^2x+3zx^2+6xyz,\end{multline}
which may be easier to remember as
$$(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3+3\bigl(xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(z+x)\bigr)+6xyz,$$
and writing $x+y=(x+y+z)-z$, &c., we obtain
$$(x+y+z)^3=x^3+y^3+z^3+3(xy+yz+zx)(x+y+z)-3xyz.$$

Comment: This is not something that will help the audience of the question, which is A Level students. They would not memorise such a formula.